# android webservice

Tags: android, web-services, webservice-client, ksoap2

I have one question regarding soap web service. I need to pass some string values and one image to the the webservice from my Android appication. I am using Ksoap2 client. I could pass string values. How I can pass image? Can anybody please help me?

Comment: have you tried to send a byte array >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the image as a png (using `Bitmap.compress` if it isn't a png file to start with) and then base-64.

Comment: I tried that .But I cant send parameters as byte array. Some serialization problem..How can I send the byte array...In the server part they are accepting byte array...please help